# How can I edit the invoice to include a VAT breakdown?

Tags: invoice, vat

Some of our items do not have VAT. So we need a table that shows a breakdown. Such as seen below. Is there any way I can do this in Magento?

%    -- Rate   -----              Net   ----        VAT
20     --Standard          100.00           --20.00
0   -   --Zero        ----     15.00           --- 0.00

Answer (score 1):

I just used Foomans PDF customiser.